# Output HTML file in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to output a block of HTML from Wordpress that looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td> Link to first headline </td>
    <td> Link to fourth headline </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Link to second headline </td>
    <td> Link to fifth headline </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Link to third headline </td>
    <td> Link to sixth headline </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I used to be able to do this with Moveable Type quite easily but cannot for the life of me figure it out. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a Custom HTML widget(**Appearance > Widgets**) or put the code in the Editor on a page. Make sure you're in the **Code Editor** and not the **Visual Editor** (There should be tabs at the top that let you switch. If you're already in the Gutenberg editor then it'll be three vertical dots on the upper right of the screen.)

For linking the headers, you can select the text and link using the link (chain-looking) icon at the top of the editor that will let you select another part of your page. This will be in the Visual Editor, though you can input your own links using the code as well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm actually trying to output that code to a HTML file on my server.

Comment: Okay! If we're talking going into files(Is your server local?), you'll have to put it in a PHP file and make sure you're calling your header and footer and the php structure so that the page loads properly. This is a tutorial on converting a full HTML site to WordPress, but there's some good info in here on file structure: [https://websitesetup.org/html-to-wordpress/]. Is this in the right direction?

Comment: Thank you for the help. Sorry for not being clear. All I really want to do is drop a file like that on my server to be read by another website entirely. The file would be populated by Wordpress entries -- the last 6 posts with headlines and links. Another website would pull that file into their site.